# Hardware components based on which to generate password

Tags: passwords, java, hardware

I want to generate a password for a Keystore in java on Windows platform.

I would like to make a HASH out of some hardware information from my computer and some salt.

My question is: which hardware or system information i should use for my password generator? I want something that is 100% guaranteed it does not change so i can generate the same password over again. This way i don't lose access to my data.

Thank you!

Comment: What if the user swaps out the hardware?

Comment: What do you gain from having a password in this scenario? Assume that an attacker knows your algorithm for generating it...

Comment: You need to define your threat model, that is, why are you doing this? I can only think you might want to do this for obfuscation, or to avoid storing your password anywhere (not even in backups). These might not be good ideas, plus your approach wouldn't be ideal anyway. So please add details to define exactly what you are protecting against.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can use the [DPAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) to protect your keystore and ensure that the data can be decrypted only on the machine on which it was encrypted (or if you want, by only the user that encrypted it).

This will be a more straight forward approach than trying to generate a hash out of hardware information, will provide the same (or better) degree of security and will have less chances of making a mistake and would also avoid the problem of hardware changes resulting in data loss.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i wanted. Do you know if there is a java implementation for this API?

Comment: @GeoM Check [this](http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

1. If you were on Linux, you could simply query [`/dev/urandom`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Random_number_generation#Kernel_built-in_RNG) to get the random value without carrying about what the source of the randomness exactly is. But yes, the device will use noise generated by the devices to increase the entropy.
2. On Windows you may use the Windows equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191335/windows-equivalent-of-dev-random
3. But you may also use everything else that is meant for crypto purposes. You have tagged your question with [java]. In Java you may use the `SecureRandom` class. The output is unpredictable and this should be the most important concern regarding a random number generator.

Comment: This does not seem to be what the OP is asking about. They want a random source that does not change over time.

Comment: Yes, i used SecureRandom class to generate my encryption KEY, but i need a password to protect it.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what OP wants. OP wants something that never changes, not something that changes all the time.